# Semicolon in URLs

Tags: http, url

I have a URL like that: **localhost:8080/demo/**

And when I call `localhost:8080/demo/'''''''''` It working fine.

But when I try with `localhost:8080/demo/;;;` It not working and return HTTP code 404 Not Found.

I tried with few special character  `# % \ ? /` , it returned 400 too.

Anyone can explain it for me? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read this and edit your question accordingly : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: 1) Did you mean "404" in both cases? 2) Is an application running at this URL? Did you program it? If not, which one is it? 3) Does `/demo/'''''''''` give the same result/content as `/demo/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These special characters are not directly allowed in URLs,
because they have special meanings there.
For example:
`/` is separator within the path,
`?` marks the query-part of an URL,
`#` marks a page-internal link,
etc.

Quoted from [Wikipedia: Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters):

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character")
>   has special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context,
>   and a URI scheme says that it is necessary to use that character
>   for some *other* purpose, then the character must be *percent-encoded*.
>   Percent-encoding a reserved character involves converting the
>   character to its corresponding byte value in ASCII and then
>   representing that value as a pair of hexadecimal digits. The digits,
>   preceded by a percent sign (%) which is used as an escape character,
>   are then used in the URI in place of the reserved character.

For example: `;` is a reserved character. Therefore, when `;` shall occur
in an URL but without having its special meaning, then it needs to be
replaced by `%3B` as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)